# Way to get volume id from snapshot id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I have a snapshot id and wanted to know if there was any way to get he volume id the snapshot came from.

Comment: EC2 returns the volume ID in the snapshot metadata. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Please edit the question and provide details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DescribeSnapshots` API call. Here's an example using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
$ aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids snap-5caa7fb4 --query 'Snapshots[*].VolumeId' --output text
vol-bd9b80c5
```